# Can't find variable: document が解決できない（ReactNative,Expo, Stripe, Djangoを使用）

Tags: django, reactjs, react-native, react-jsx

ReactNative、Django歴半年、Stripe歴二ヶ月の新米です。よろしくお願い致します。

ReactNativeでStripeを使用したいのですが、
リロード時に毎回ターミナルに黄文字でエラーが記載されてしまいます。

documentというものは使用していないような気がするのですが、どのようにアプローチすればよいか全くわかりません。

Can't find variable: document
[image: エラーのスクショ]

```
Can't find variable: document
at node_modules/@stripe/stripe-js/dist/stripe.js:8:17 in findScript
at node_modules/@stripe/stripe-js/dist/stripe.js:74:8 in Promise$argument_0
at http://127.0.0.1:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:198110:31 in loadScript
```

```
package.json

  "dependencies": {
    "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.8.1",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.31.0",
    "@stripe/stripe-react-native": "^0.9.0",
    "expo-stripe-checkout": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-stripe-checkout-webview": "^0.0.13",
    "stripe": "^9.1.0",
}
```

```
App.jsx

import React from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import CheckoutWithStripe from './src/screens/CheckoutWithStripe';



// eslint-disable-next-line react/function-component-definition
export default function App() {
  return (
        <NavigationContainer>
          <CheckoutWithStripe />
        </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  headerButton: {
    marginRight: 16,
    marginTop: 6,
  },
  headerButtonText: {
    color: '#fff',
    backgroundColor: '#10b981',
  },
});
```

```
CheckoutWithStripe.jsx

import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { View, Text, ActivityIndicator} from "react-native";
import Button from "../components/Button";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
import { StripeProvider } from "@stripe/stripe-react-native";
import PaymentForm from "../components/PaymentForm";

const apiUrl = 'myUrl';

export default function CheckoutWithStripe() {
    return (
        <StripeProvider
            publishableKey="publishableKey"
            merchantIdentifier="merchant.identifier"
        >
            <SafeAreaView>
                <Text>
                    決済画面になります。
                </Text>
                <PaymentForm />
                <Button label="Pay" />
            </SafeAreaView>
        </StripeProvider>
    )
}
```

```
PaymentForm.jsx

import React from 'react'
import { CardField } from '@stripe/stripe-react-native';

export default function PaymentForm() {
  return (
    <CardField
    postalCodeEnabled={true}
    placeholder={{
        number: '4242 4242 4242 4242',
    }}
    cardStyle={{
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
        textColor: '#000000',
    }}
    style={{
        width: '100%',
        height: 50,
        marginVertical: 30,
      }}
      onCardChange={(cardDetails) => {
        console.log('cardDetails', cardDetails);
      }}
      onFocus={(focusedField) => {
        console.log('focusField', focusedField);
      }}
/>
  )
}
```

Comment: ちなみにstripe-react-nativeのインストールはどのようにして、どのバージョンがインストールされていますか？

Comment: npm installでインストールをし、 "@stripe/stripe-react-native": "^0.9.0"が入っております